# Exporting data from a plot in Netlogo and getting moved commas

Tags: netlogo

Well, I've made an agent based model in Netlogo.

I got a plot where I count the mean of some variables. Here's the result.

[image]

As you can see, there are no values higher than 5 points.

But, when i export data in a csv file, I get this:

[image]

It seems like there are moved commas...How is that possible? Is there any way that I could avoid this error?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What does the actual CSV data look like, if you view it as plain text (and not by using e.g. a spreadsheet application)?

Comment: Actually, that's a really good question.

Comment: "x","y","color","pen down?","x","y","color","pen down?","x","y","color","pen down?","x","y","color","pen down?"
"0","4","0","true","0","4","5","true","0","3.5","15","true","0","3.5","25","true"
"1","4.340750000000004","0","true","1","3.8328333333333306","5","tru

Comment: What I can see is that commas are in the correct position, so the problem begins when I import it with excel, How can I proceed to avoid the error? I use normal import, signaling commas as separator.

Comment: I don't use Excel myself, but I've seen problems like this arise based on locale settings. e.g. in the US we write "3.1415" but in Germany they write "3,1415"

Comment: Libreoffice made it!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!